# Google play concern on cyanogen

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-store, google-play-services

I want to get Google play on my Cyanogen 13 (6.0) and i discovered
openGAPPS.
Do you need Google play services in order for google play to work?
I'm concern about the privacy implications and permissions that putting google play with this underlying updateing service will bring.
Could someone explain to me how does google play behave?
What's happening under the hood so to speak?
Does it have power to monitor app usage of the downloaded apps from the store?
I wanted to install the pico install from openGAPPS becouse it does provides just google play.

Comment: Google Play Services are essential for Google Play Apps to work. It provides the infrastructure for certain low level services such as location tracking, etc. It also provides the updation service where it provides updates to apps on your phone, and also keeps your Google Sign In intact, syncing all your data with your account. Hence it is necessary for Google services to operate. As for pico installer, can't help you there, never tried it myself.

Comment: I know that you can opt out of google location services but my bigger question is does google play services or google play have any insights what am i doing inside of those apps? Does google play services behave like a normal app and by that i mean does it need permissions and asks for them? Because I have a way to control certain permissions on cyanogen.

Comment: You can always check the permissions required by Google Play Services on the app page on the Play Store. The Play Services package isn't a regular app, but a framework packaged in as a .apk, which is required by almost all Google apps to operate.